# HTML5 Video poster attribute in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, html, webkit

In Firefox the image specified by the poster attribute of the `VIDEO` tag remains on screen until the play button is pressed. However in the Webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome) the poster is dumped in favor of the first frame from the video as soon as the video metadata is fetched.

I want to avoid having to place the poster on top of the video element manually if I could. Does anyone know of a fix for this?

```
<video src="some_url" poster="images/poster.jpg">
    <source type="video/ogg" src="some_url" />
</video>
```

Comment: The issue has been reported at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1007988

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that WebKit strips the attribute as soon as the video is fethced, because iOS 3.x for Iphone and Ipad has a serious bug where it is not possible to play the video at all when there is a poster attribute specified. This was fixed in iOS 4, but the workaround still stays, even in Safari 5...There are a lot of users who didn't upgrade to iOS 4 yet, so no luck with the poster...

I'm going to try and position the image absolutely over the video using Javascript, and removing it when the video is played - that seems like the best solution...

Comment: Yeah I thought I may have to end up doing that. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: Anyone got simple example code showing how to do this? Looks like it's not necessary on iOS builds of Safari…

Answer (score 6):

If you can get away with not preloading the video you can set preload="none" on the video element. In Safari this results in the poster being displayed.

Safari on iOS probably sets preload="none" as the default to save bandwidth, while the desktop version preloads unless you explicitly tell it not to.

Comment: This did not work for Safari on Windows, but it looks like it might start working in future browser versions. Also, this did the trick for me in IE9.

Comment: it works only till the video is loaded so it displays for a bit but then as soon as the video is loaded the poster disappears.

Answer (score 0):

It's 2020 Jan. so you may figure out the solution.
but I left my solution for other people.
Many people say it's a bug. but I disagree.
It's just a difference between firefox and chrome/edge.

Suppose you have `<video preload="metadata">` in your HTML and post to the server thumbnail image. then you'll change the poster value to the src server gives to you.
like this:

```
xhr.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      const data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      player.poster = `/image/${data.thumbnailMain}`; // change the poster value
      player.load();                                  // then load.
    } else {
      console.error(this.responseText);
    }
  });
```

In firefox, video tag is designed when poster property value changes, it will load automatically. but chrome/edge won't `load()`;
so you should `player.load()` manually;

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
<video src="video/video.mp4#t=0.5" playsinline controls preload="metadata">
      <source src="video/video.mp4#t=0.5" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide more information as to how the code you've provided works, what you have changed, etc. Code-only answers might solve the problem of the original asker but they don't help future readers understand the solution.